# How do i display proper image credit?

Tags: wordpress

so I am just baffled at how WordPress doesn't have a function to display an image source with a url that will display in my posts. I am aware you can use the caption for this by including html in it but this is very tedious if when I am doing a lot of postings a day. Is there an easier alternative? I tried adding custom meta fields to attachment but cannot get it to display under my images in a post.

I don't understand why this is not built into wordpress. This is so crucial for the web.

Comment: Really? Putting a line of text underneath an image is "crucial for the web"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way to add credit link, you have to develop a custom WordPress theme with an additional input  field for each images to enter credit url .
Hire a WordPress developer for this purpose